# XSLT group-by based on ID value child

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I want to transform an xml with a multiple header, detail, and moredetail nodes.  Each node contains key "ID" to tie them together.
this seems pretty simple, but its not working for me.

Start with the below xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<File>
    <Header>
        <Id>1</Id>
        <Other>How</Other>
    </Header>
    <Detail>
        <Id>1</Id>
        <Other>to</Other>
    </Detail>
    <MoreDetails>
        <Id>1</Id>
        <Other>group</Other>
    </MoreDetails>
    <Header>
        <Id>2</Id>
        <Other>How</Other>
    </Header>
    <Detail>
        <Id>2</Id>
        <Other>to</Other>
    </Detail>
    <MoreDetails>
        <Id>2</Id>
        <Other>group</Other>
    </MoreDetails>
    <MoreDetails>
        <Id>2</Id>
        <Other>may have multiples</Other>
    </MoreDetails>
</File>
```

Produce something like the following either with Group1, Group2 etc. or Group value=1, Group value=2 etc.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<File>
    <Group value="1">
        <Header>
            <Id>1</Id>
            <Other>How</Other>
        </Header>
        <Detail>
            <Id>1</Id>
            <Other>to</Other>
        </Detail>
        <MoreDetails>
            <Id>1</Id>
            <Other>group</Other>
        </MoreDetails>
    </Group>
    <Group value="2">
        <Header>
            <Id>2</Id>
            <Other>How</Other>
        </Header>
        <Detail>
            <Id>2</Id>
            <Other>to</Other>
        </Detail>
        <MoreDetails>
            <Id>2</Id>
            <Other>group</Other>
        </MoreDetails>
        <MoreDetails>
            <Id>2</Id>
            <Other>with multiple child</Other>
        </MoreDetails>
    </Group>
</File>
```

I started with something like this,

```
 <xsl:template match="/File">

        <xsl:for-each-group select="./child::*" group-by="Id">
            <xsl:variable name="ID" select="Id"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="current-grouping-key()"/>
```

and variations using variables and key names, but i'm not able to output as specified.

Any ideas very welcome.
Thanks in advance
-ac

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `current-group()` to access the nodes in the group.

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
  version="2.0">

  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/File">
    <File>
      <xsl:for-each-group select="./child::*" group-by="Id">
        <Group value="{Id}">
          <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()"/>
        </Group>
      </xsl:for-each-group>
    </File>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: That works great.   The closest I had was this (below), but the last node was not formed correctly.  Thanks for the perfect solution.

Comment: ahh, can't post my xsl.. yours is better anyhow. thanks again.